# Semantic Search on Documents saved in oracle DB

Tags: oracle, search

How  can I  build a semantic search on documents(pdf, word) saved on relational oracle tables. Does Oracle have  tools for semantic search? Plese help with some instructions to do that search or some documentation to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oracle documentation on the ORACLE_TEXT option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/quicktour.htm#g1011793)